# Use regular expressions to extract integer which precedes some given characters

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function that will take an input String and read it line by line, and what I'm looking to do is convert units of measurements between metric and imperial.

Obviously that actual conversion between miles/kilometers and kilograms/pounds is straightforward math, but I'm a bit stumped on the correct way to go about extracting these integers so i can convert them.

To make things more difficult, the input will vary, and I'm going to need to identify different formats (spaces between integer and unit of measurement, different spellings [miles,mile,mi,km,kilometer etc])

Now I've got

```
if (isMetric) {
            for (String line : input.split("[\\r\\n]+")) {

            }
            return input;
        }
```

To read each line, and i'm thinking i might need to use a combination of `String.substring` as well as Regex, but I'm pretty new.

Any sort of guidance or links to helpful articles would be much appreciated, I'm not exactly looking for a straight up solution here of course!

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

For example as you asked:

Input:

`I ran 50miles today, 1mile yesterday, and I also lifted a 20 pound and a 5lb weight!`

Output:

`I ran 80km today, 1.6km yesterday, and I also lifted a 9kg and a 2.2kg weight!`

Comment: You should try to describe your input and the expected output more precisely.

Comment: I think you can solve your problem with StringTokenizer class

Comment: put here your input and expected out put.

Comment: I've added an example for you guys

Comment: "Any sort of guidance or links to helpful articles would be much appreciated" an off-topic request for an external resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that will let you find all matches with or without spaces, and with different unit spellings.

Note that in the patterns, it is important that all units that have a prefix come before their prefix (so here, `miles` must come before `mil`).

```
// \d+ matches a number. \s* matches any number of spaces.
String milePattern = "(\\d+)\\s*((miles)|(mile)|(mil))";
String kmPattern = "(\\d+)\\s*((kilometers)|(km)|(kilometres))";

// Compile the patterns (you should not do that at each method call, in your real code)
Pattern mileP = Pattern.compile(milePattern);
Pattern kmP = Pattern.compile(kmPattern);

// You can match one or multiple lines all the same.
String input = "I ran 1001km or 601 mile \n that is the same as 602 mil or 603miles or 1002 kilometers.";

// Create matcher instance on your input.
Matcher mileM = mileP.matcher(input);
// Iterate over all mile-matches (find will 'advance' each time you call it)
while (mileM.find()) {
    // Retrieve the value and the unit
    String amount = mileM.group(1);
    String unit = mileM.group(2);

    // You can also access some data about the match
    int idx = mileM.start();

    // And do whatever you need with it
    System.out.println("Found a mile value: " + amount + " with unit " + unit + " starting at index: " + idx);
}
```

You can do the same as I did with the miles but with the kilometer pattern. You could also combine both expressions if you want. In my test case I get the output:

```
Found a mile value: 601 with unit mile starting at index: 16
Found a mile value: 602 with unit mil starting at index: 47
Found a mile value: 603 with unit miles starting at index: 58
Found a km value: 1001 with unit km starting at index: 6
Found a km value: 1002 with unit kilometers starting at index: 70
```

You can then do whatever conversion you want, or rebuild the string with other units.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot. Just a quick question - would the best way to replace the values of amount and units (with the converted equivilants) be simply mileM.group(i).replace(mileM.group(i), NEWVALUE)? That doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: Actually I would imagine you would need to use the original string, and use the index/length of the found values and replace them from there?

Comment: Yeah at first glance that seems reasonable (your second comment, not the first). Reuse the characters that are between the end-index of the previous match and the start-index of the current match. Then append the converted values corresponding to the current match.